# Printing pyramid in Java on the console

Tags: java

How can I print a pyramid in Java like this

```
1
23
456
78910
```

My current code looks like this:

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, num = 1;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.println(num);
                num++;
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

If I try this removing declared `i` & `j` then it shows an array out of bounds exception
However  'i' & 'j' are creating the problem. What should my code look like.

Comment: did you pass _any_ command-line arguments to the program?

Comment: i am new to coding sir .so i dont know what you taking about..please explain me command-line arguments to the function also

Comment: you are reading from `args[0]`. What do you expect is its value?

Comment: @user2502227 basically what command you are using to run this programme.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: i am using eclipse to run this

Comment: then you need to either use the console for input (look up `Scanner` and `System.in` or define the command-line arguments in the project configuration ("configure command-line arguments in eclipse")

Comment: yep. look up "java command line parameters" or "run java from command line [your os here]"

Comment: Please be so kind to review and spell check your question at the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int val=1;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
             System.out.print(val);
            val++;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

initially val is equal to 1 . Inside the first `for` loop i=0 and j with increase from 1, but when i=0 second for loop doesn't run. then you get the first value as 1. Then it will point to new line.

When i=1,j still 1 so second `for` loop runs 1 time and print 2, because val has increment(val++). when j=2 in inside `for` loop it is not running only print the new value (3) of val there.

so on this will work

Comment: huh? Explanation is needed here

Comment: this code done the trick.....i love you man ..u just save me from my terrible teacher

Comment: @user2502227 and yet, did you learn anything from this answer?

Comment: @user2502227 this is not YouTube, please try and use common English sentences and titles

Comment: This is not quite difficult to understand:
You have two `for` loops, the first/upper one to create the new line.
The second one writes the numbers. 
This should be basic knowledge of java (here: `for` loops).

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 1;
    //i is how many numbers per row
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        //prints i numbers because j increases from 0 to i, incrementing num each time
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            System.out.print(num++);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This code will work for your purposes.

Now, please read on if you would like to understand Java better and see why the compiler was throwing errors in your code. You shouldn't use stackoverflow to copy in paste someone else's code without understanding it. In your code, you were declaring`i` and `j` twice. In Java, you cannot declare a variable twice. You did it first in `int i,j,  num = 1;` and then again in each for loop `for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)`. You could correct this by saying `for(i = 1; i <= lines; i++)`. Notice how the `int` is left out in the second version of the `for` loop. You can simply assign a value to a variable in a for loop rather than creating a new variable as you do when declare the type `int i = 1`

The syntax of a for loop is:

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)

{
   //Statements
}
```

The initialization step is executed first, and only once. This step allows you to declare and initialize any loop control variables. You are not required to put a statement here, as long as a semicolon appears.

As for the array out of bounds error that you receive, you are trying to read in a command line argument in the statement `int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` Notice how the main method has a parameter `String[] args`. These are called command line arguments and can be passed in if you manually run the program from the command line. You were trying to read in `args[0]` which is outside of the bounds of `args[]`.

In other words, if you run

```
java MyProgram one two
```

Then args contains:

[ "one", "two" ]

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   String one = args[0]; //=="one"
   String two = args[1]; //=="two"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you give the number of lines as your only argument, so the code would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int lines = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(num);
            num++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int l=1;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
     for (int k=0; k<5-i; k++)
     {
        System.out.print(" ");          
     }
     for (int j=0; j<(i*2)+1; j++)
     {
        if(j%2!=0){
            System.out.print(l++);
        }else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }           
     }
     System.out.println("");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void pyramid(int max) {
    int num = 1;
    max = 4;
    for (int row = 0; row < max; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < max; column++) 
            System.out.print(column <= row ? num++ : " ");
        System.out.println();
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author shelc
 */
public class PrintNumberPyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the count : ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        //enter the number of rows you want to print
        pyramid(number);

    }

    public static void pyramid(int rows) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                System.out.print(j <= i ? count++ : " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).