# return incompatible types (java)

Tags: java, return

Original:
Okay so I have to make a simple number pyramid but the catch is that it has to use two methods. My problem is that return keeps giving me "Incompatible types" and I have no clue as to why.
Okay so I have to make a simple number pyramid but the catch is that it has to use two methods. My problem is that return keeps giving me "Incompatible types" and I have no clue as to why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println(NumPyramid(1,1));
} 
public static int NumPyramid(int i, int j)
 {
    for (;i <= 7; i++) 
{
  for (; j <= i; j++)
{        
{    
   return System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
} 
}
```

Edit: okay so now my new code has the problem of not being a pyramid

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    NumPyramid(1,1);
} 
public static void NumPyramid(int i, int j)
{
    for (;i <= 7; i++) 
    {
      for (; j <= i; j++)
      {      
          System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
      System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

this prints out

`1
2
3
4
5
6
7`

removing the Println gives `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

The output should be 
`1
12
123`
etc,

Comment: What does `System.out.print(..)` do and what value (if any) does it resolve to?

Comment: are you confused with the `C`'s `printf()`/`scanf()` functions?

Comment: It is supposed to actually print the values and return to the main method which formats it correctly.

Comment: What is NumPyramid supposed to do? I am thinking if you want to print a pyramid of numbers, is it enough for NumPyramid() to accept 1 parameter which is the height of pyramid. The function will then print all levels Of the pyramid.

Comment: This should be helpful for printing a pyramid. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17349536/3328790

Comment: This should help you with the pyramid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17349536/3328790

Comment: My problem is returning the pyramid, not creating it

Comment: Can you say if any of the answers helped you?

Comment: if you got a new question, make it a new post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, as @makoto points out cleverly, `System.out.print` being a `void` method, it returns nothing so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(NumPyramid(1,1));
}
```

should be changed as well. So you shall make:

```
public static void NumPyramid(int i, int j) {
  for (;i <= 7; i++) {
    for (; j <= i; j++) {       
       System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
  } 
}
```

a void method, and :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumPyramid(1,1);
}
```

not getting printed.

*Edit*

**When you got a new question, you shall not edit your question, removing stuff in the question's post to make it into a new one… But instead accept the best answer, and make a *new* post. Here we are not answering only to *you*, but we are building a knowledge base. If you have a new question, make it a new post!**

That said, for your new question, what your algorithm is off, it should instead be:

```
public static void NumPyramid(int max) {
    for (int i=1; i<=max; ++i) {
        for (int j=1; j<=i; ++j)
            System.out.println(j + " "); 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

- having a single argument `max` to specify the number of lines, and the width of the "base" of the pyramid ;
- iterate using `i` for `max` carriage return output ;
- iterate using `j` for `i` numbers
- start iterations at 1, so we don't output `0 1 2` for `max = 3` but `1 2 3`

which should output, with max = 3

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

HTH, again. And please, please, restore your original question.

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.print` is a `void` method; that is, it returns nothing.

You can't return something from a `void` method.

Simply remove the `return` keyword from that line, change the signature of your method from `int` to `void`.

Then, change the call in your main method to remove the `System.out.println` from it.

Comment: It will not work, because `NumPyramid` is declared to return an `int`. So, there must be a `return` in that method that returns a value.

Comment: Good catch you two.  Made the revision.

Comment: It will still not work, because in the `main` method he is printing the return value of the `NumPyramid` method. If that method is `void`, you'll get a compile error in the `main` method.

Comment: Made that revision as well.

Comment: I then lose the pyramid itself, by not having a println I get 1-7 all on the same line and if I add it into the for loop it then prints 1-7 on each individual line, but no 123, 1234, etc.

Comment: the poster's program has problem. change NumPyramid()'s return type to  void. And just call it in the main will solve it

Comment: @user3326162 I recommend you to see zmo answer, he gives you full code

Comment: @Frakcool It doesn't print correctly though, only 1-7 on one line. I need a pyramid...

Answer (score 0):

You want to print this?

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

You need one argument, and it's the method:

```
public static void NumPyramid(int number)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= i; ++x)
        {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I think it's self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not asking about incompatible return types anymore? Well, I can answer the question you have now, I think.

If you want the code to be in a pyramid, you can't do this:

```
for (;i <= 7; i++) 
{
  for (; j <= i; j++)
  {      
      System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
  System.out.println();
}
```

What that code is doing is printing the value of j, then a space, and then printing a new line. A solution is to create a String that you use to store the numbers after each iteration of the for loops.

```
for (;i <= 7; i++) 
{
  for (; j <= i; j++)
  {      
      //System.out.print(j + " ");
      //The string would take the place of this line
    }
  //Since println always prints on a new line, you 
  //could just print the string in this System.out
  System.out.println();
}
```